# Making code run on click R presentation

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, r-markdown, rpres

I'm currently making a presentation using Rstudio's R presentation functionality.

I have an algorithm which loops through and plots a graph every second or two.
The algorithm can be called via `RunAlgorithm()`

```
RunAlgorithm<-function(){
    for(i in 1:10){
        x<-rnorm(1000)
        y<-runif(1000)
        plot(x,y)
        Sys.sleep(1)
    }
}
```

I want to show this algorithm running in the presentation. But when I use it in the file (below), I just get a whole page of each individual plot, one displayed right after the next

[image]

## TestFile.Rpres

````
    TestFile
========================================================
author: me
date: today

First Slide
========================================================
```{r echo = FALSE}
RunAlgorithm<-function(){
        for(i in 1:10){
            x<-rnorm(1000)
            y<-runif(1000)
            plot(x,y)
            Sys.sleep(1)
        }
}
RunAlgorithm()

```
Slide With Code
========================================================


Slide 2
````

What I would like is some way to click a button, or turn onto this slide and have the animation play in browser

Answer (score 1):

A R presentation as any RMarkdown document. is not something dynamic like eg. a shiny app. The result is a static html file. So what you need is to create an animation that you can include in the presentation. This is partly anwered in [Combining R Markdown and Animation Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038893/combining-r-markdown-and-animation-package) but I could not get it to work for me. So I found this [example](https://github.com/yufree/democode/blob/master/rreport/animation.Rpres).

So for you it would look like

````
```{r setup,echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(animation.fun = hook_scianimator)
```

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://vis.supstat.com//assets/themes/dinky/css/scianimator.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vis.supstat.com/assets/themes/dinky/js/jquery.scianimator.min.js"></script>

    TestFile
========================================================
author: me
date: today

First Slide
========================================================
```{r echo = FALSE, fig.show='animate', interval=1}
RunAlgorithm<-function(){
        for(i in 1:10){
            x<-rnorm(1000)
            y<-runif(1000)
            plot(x,y)
        }
}
RunAlgorithm()
```
Slide With Code
========================================================


Slide 2
````

EDIT:

It also works with `opts_knit$set(animation.fun = hook_ffmpeg_html)` but not in the R-Studio preview but only after you clicked on More -> Save As Web Page... . Note, that you have to have ffmpeg installed and in your path.